# Adding custom function and promise to React.lazy causing error

Tags: reactjs, es6-promise, code-splitting

I'm using `React.lazy` to do [route-based code splitting](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#route-based-code-splitting). Additionally, I'm adding a minimum delay as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54159114/6899860). The purpose of the delay is to show a load animation for a minimum amount of time on each lazy load.

Everything works fine when I have each route setup as below:

```
const ExampleComponent = React.lazy(() => 
  Promise.all([
    import('./ExampleRoute'),
    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, MIN_DELAY))
  ])
  .then(([moduleExports]) => moduleExports));
```

However, when I try to move my promise to a function everything breaks:

```
const lazyPromise = (route) =>
  Promise.all([
    import(route),
    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, MIN_DELAY))
  ])
  .then(([moduleExports]) => moduleExports);

const ExampleComponent = React.lazy(() => lazyPromise('./ExampleRoute'));
```

The error I'm getting: **Cannot find module './ExampleRoute'**

What am I missing here? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Webpack wasn't configured for code splitting. It doesn't know that `ExampleRoute` needs to be included into the bundle. See https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports

Comment: You cannot pass a variable to `import`. The module bundler can't figure out which module to include while bundling because that variable value is only available at runtime.

Comment: Ahh I see. That makes sense. Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question to help anyone who comes across this in the future. This answer elaborates on the comments from **estus** and **Prakash Sharma** above.

`webpack` must be statically buildable, and does not support the use of any path variables, [including query strings](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2992#issuecomment-247833228). If a value is not available until runtime, `webpack` will not be able to see it.

More information about how `webpack` handles code-splitting can be found [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting).