# How to add a minimum delay to a React Suspense component when you do not have control over the AJAX call because you are using a library?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, i18next, react-i18next, react-suspense

I have the following component wrapped in a `Suspense` one:

```
// ...
render(
      <Suspense fallback={<LoadingSpinner />}>
         <MyComponent {...props} />
      </Suspense>
)
// ...
```

`MyComponent` uses `i18next`, which triggers a suspense which loads translations.
Eveything works, but the spinner is showed only for an instant and then it disappears because the AJAX requests `i18next` is making completes.

Can I tell the `Suspense` component to somehow show the spinner at least for 2 seconds? This would improve the UX visually.
It would be great to have something like this:

```
// ...
// minDuration - 2 seconds
render(
      <Suspense fallback={<LoadingSpinner />} minDuration={2000}>
         <MyComponent {...props} />
      </Suspense>
)
// ...
```

I do not have control over the `i18next` AJAX, or I think so, as it is a library.

Is it possible to achieve what I want with `Suspense`?

Comment: I don't think react has this functionality yet, but you can achieve this by adding a `setTimeout` for your `AJAX` call i.e. calling your API after 2 seconds using `setTimeout`. - `setTimeout(function(){Call your API here},2000) `

Comment: I tried with Promise.all and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React suspense/lazy delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54158994/react-suspense-lazy-delay)