# TypeScript + React.Lazy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
const Game = React.lazy(() => new Promise( (resolve) => {
    setTimeout( () => resolve(import('./Game')) , 1000)
}))
```

Error : Error:(6, 35) TS2345: Argument of type 'Promise<typeof import("D:/PROGECTS/SnakeReactReduxTS/snake-react-redux-ts/src/Components/Stages/Game")>' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ default: never; } | PromiseLike<{ default: never; }> | undefined'.
Type 'Promise<typeof import("D:/PROGECTS/SnakeReactReduxTS/snake-react-redux-ts/src/Components/Stages/Game")>' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<{ default: never; }>'.
Types of property 'then' are incompatible.
Type '<TResult1 = typeof import("D:/PROGECTS/SnakeReactReduxTS/snake-react-redux-ts/src/Components/Stages/Game"), TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: typeof import("D:/PROGECTS/SnakeReactReduxTS/snake-react-redux-ts/src/Components/Stages/Game")) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<...>) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reaso...' is not assignable to type '<TResult1 = { default: never; }, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: { default: never; }) => TResult1 | PromiseLike) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) | null | undefined) => PromiseLike<...>'.
Types of parameters 'onfulfilled' and 'onfulfilled' are incompatible.
Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
Property 'default' is missing in type 'typeof import("D:/PROGECTS/SnakeReactReduxTS/snake-react-redux-ts/src/Components/Stages/Game")' but required in type '{ default: never; }'.

What does he want from me?

Comment: Hi, please give us more information about what are you going to do? What efforts did you make and what is the problem are you facing? And, please, please, make the error log easy to read

Comment: I want to make simulate delay. The code works fine on JS, I just  want to typify it

Answer (score 4):

`lazy` function returns a promise of { default: ... } object which being called asynchronously and will `await` till promise being not resolved that beind delayed for `1000 ms` and in the end will import the `Game` component and return it.

```
    const Game = React.lazy(async () => {
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
      return import('./Game');
    });
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Typescript swears.  I need to typify it

Comment: Works for me beautifully in Typescript and on top of that is also easy to read in its sequence, so an example where async/await can improve readability.

Answer (score 1):

> What does he want from me?

What do you want from him ?

`React.lazy` should be used like that:

```
const Game = React.lazy(() => import('./Game'));
```

You may have a more specific use-case (tell us) but the basic usage is like that.

I invite you to read the doc https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy

Comment: I want to make simulate delay

Comment: This answer does not answer the original question; see @solanki... below for an answer that correctly works with Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const Game = React.lazy(() => import('./Game'))
```

You have try this

Comment: I want to make simulate delay

Answer (score 0):

`React.lazy` wants a default export. If your `'./Game'` doesn't `export default`, this won't work.

You could try this (where I'm guessing you're exporting a component called `Game` in the `'./Game'` file). Otherwise, use a default export.

```js
const Game = React.lazy(() => new Promise( (resolve) => {
    setTimeout( () => resolve({default: import('./Game').Game}) , 1000)
}))
```